# How to show sub-menu of a MainMenu programmatically?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, mainmenu

I need programmatically to show a sub-menu of main menu on a form in Winform .NΕΤ application (classes `MainMenu` with `MenuItem`).

- E.g. show sub-menu with all items of menu item File.
- E.g. same as pressing Alt-F if menu item text is &File.

I have tried to call `OnPopup()`, `PerformClick()`, `PerformSelect()`, and sending `WM_MenuSelect` message; sub-menu does not open.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Should be tags for these old components. `mainmenu`, `contextmenu`, ...etc.

Comment: I created a tag for `MainMenu`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To show a menu item of a legacy [`MainMenu`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.mainmenu?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8) component, you need to call [`TrackPopupMenuEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-trackpopupmenu?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235) and pass the menu item handle to it. To show it in the correct location, as when you click on the menu item, get the menu item rectangle using [`GetMenuItemRect`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getmenuitemrect?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235).

[image] 
[image]

Here is the code:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern int TrackPopupMenuEx(IntPtr hmenu, uint fuFlags,
    int x, int y, IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lptpm);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern bool GetMenuItemRect(IntPtr hWnd, IntPtr hMenu,
    uint uItem, out RECT lprcItem);
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
static extern IntPtr SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, int wParam, IntPtr lParam);
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT { public int Left, Top, Right, Bottom; }
const int TPM_RIGHTBUTTON = 0x2;
const int TPM_RETURNCMD = 0x100;
const int WM_SYSCOMMAND = 0x112;

public void ShowSubMenu(MenuItem menuItem, bool asContextMenu = false)
{
    var mainMenu = menuItem.GetMainMenu();
    var form = mainMenu.GetForm();
    var x = 0; var y = 0;
    if (asContextMenu)
    {
        x = MousePosition.X; y = MousePosition.Y;
    }
    else
    {
        GetMenuItemRect(form.Handle, mainMenu.Handle, 
            (uint)menuItem.Index, out RECT rect);
        x = rect.Left; y = rect.Bottom;
    }
    var command = TrackPopupMenuEx(menuItem.Handle, TPM_RETURNCMD | TPM_RIGHTBUTTON,
        x, y, form.Handle, IntPtr.Zero);
    if (command > 0)
        SendMessage(form.Handle, WM_SYSCOMMAND, command, IntPtr.Zero);
}
```

To use it, just call it this way:

```
ShowSubMenu(fileMenuItem);
```

If you call it by passing false to `showAxContextMenu`, it will show the sub menu in the mouse position:

```
ShowSubMenu(fileMenuItem, true);
```

> **Note:** It's recommended to use a [`MenuStrip`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.menustrip?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5003235&view=netframework-4.8)
>   instead of a `MainMenu`.

Comment: Beautiful as usual, And thank you for adding the tags.

Answer (score 1):

You need to clone the required menu items to a new `ContextMenu` component in the Form's constructor or Load event and attach it to the `ContextMenu`(not  `ContextMenuStrip`) property of the target control.

For example, to clone the *New*, *Open*, and *Save* items from the *File* menu into a new `ContextMenu`:

```cs
var cmn = new ContextMenu();

cmn.MenuItems.AddRange(
    new[]
    {
        mnuFileNew.CloneMenu(),
        mnuFileOpen.CloneMenu(),
        mnuFileSave.CloneMenu()
    }
);
```

Or, if you need them all:

```
mnuFile.MenuItems.Cast<MenuItem>().ToList()
    .ForEach(m => cmn.MenuItems.Add(m.CloneMenu()));
```

Note that, the sub items will be cloned too if any.

And assign it to a `ContextMenu` property:

```cs
this.ContextMenu = cmn;
```

Now right click on the form and the new `ContextMenu` will pop up, click an item and the same code will be executed.